# How to set environmental variable within a virtualenv in makefile?

Tags: python-2.7, makefile

I have a make file with the following target:

```
.virtualenv:
    virtualenv .virtualenv -p python2.7
    (. .virtualenv/bin/activate; \
    WORK_GROUP=<my-work-group> DATABASE=<my-database>; \
    pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements_test.txt)
```

I need to set WORK_GROUP and DATABASE as environmental variable in virtualenv. so far I have tried as above but it fails.

Comment: Probably you have `export `them... it doesn't do much to set them in the current shell, without exporting them, if they need to be used by `pip` etc.

Comment: I am accessing these variables in a python script and its say key error when I access it. os.environ["WORK_GROUP"']

Comment: Yes, well, did you try my suggestion and `export` them?